# Optimizing spawning 500 objects every 3 seconds

Tags: unity, c#, optimization

Using Object Pooling, assuming I'll like to spawn 500 cubes once every three seconds. How do I make it performance friendly? I need ideas, not the code itself.

Comment: Are the cubes suppose to move ? or are they completely static ?

Comment: They are not static, their only job is to rotate and nothing else, and it is done on one line of code: transform.rotate();

Comment: I think you should start with GPU instancing them - this will increase your overall performance - however for spawning (in this case pushing more transforms to GPU can still have some overhead) but you should try first if you already didnt

Comment: Okay, I'll use GPU instancing and see the results.

Comment: Perhaps you will want to use some mixed approach : thats depends on the map - if you have a large map - then you will want to cluster the instanced actors (no idea what is the Unity term) for areas - because instancing means no occlusion checks - means every single instance will always be rendered. clusterizing by many instancing actors you can take some benefit of not rendering all of the cubes.

Comment: Just on an empty scene, it's like space simulation: where in a void, there's the Sun, 8 planets, and hundreds of Asteroids, space stations and space debris, and 5 ships that travels randomly and infinitely towards any direction. I've used a lot of optimization techniques to get the best  FPS, everything is accounted for except asteroid spawn ins and I'm getting 120-200fps, but when I spawn in asteroids(represented with cubes) only around the player but in a reasonable distance from the player, at that particular frame, I'll go down 60fps.

Comment: Then instancing should help you - if you can also delete the asteroids that are not visible - will be greater.

Comment: Generally object pooling is good for reusing the same objects. For example if you are making FPS game you can pool bullets - then you will spawn them once in memory and jut reuse them every time a shot is required.

Comment: OK thank you, I'll tell you the results later.

Comment: Yeah I know, I don't instantiate all the time.

Comment: Idea: You should probably be looking at DOTS - https://unity.com/dots

Answer (score 0):

in unity basically pooling means: instead of using `Instatntiate()` that makes new object in the scene that takes cpu performance to allocate, make all of needed object on the start of the scene and only enable and disable them and only make new object when all of you instantiated objects are active and are not ready to reuse.

you can use a `foreach` or `for` loop to look for in-active object to use it on a list but its not much performant. using a static array is much more performant than a list. as i searched on unity its best to use queue to make pooling. just en-queue an object that is ready to use and de-queue when it gets active.

just check this *brackes* link to check how its used:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tdSmKaJvCoA

Comment: I know about this, and yes, I've seen Brackeys' YouTube video on Object Pooling and applied it, but I still have performance spikes on the frames that I enable an object.

Comment: @MetaMax you are enabling many object in 3 seconds. its not a big deal but having more cpu usage in these moment dont thing is something weired